# Azure, I'm trying to add fucntions to my function app via bicep but am unsure how to do so

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep

I have a function app for a bicep file as shown  below. I want to be able to have functions in my function app when it's created. Currently I'm only able to create an empty function app with the file below.
The tutorials I've used so far don't specify how to add functions.  Please advise.

```
param FunctionApp_Name string = 'HSLDFSCustomApiFunction'
param serverfarms_UKSouthPlan_externalid string 

resource FunctionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: FunctionApp_Name
  location: 'uksouth'
  kind: 'functionapp'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    hostNameSslStates: [
      {
        name: 'hsldfsazurecustomerportalapifunctions.azurewebsites.net'
        sslState: 'Disabled'
        hostType: 'Standard'
      }
      {
        name: 'hsldfsazurecustomerportalapifunctions.scm.azurewebsites.net'
        sslState: 'Disabled'
        hostType: 'Repository'
      }
    ]
    serverFarmId: serverfarms_UKSouthPlan_externalid
    reserved: false
    isXenon: false
    hyperV: false
    siteConfig: {
      numberOfWorkers: 1
      acrUseManagedIdentityCreds: false
      alwaysOn: false
      http20Enabled: false
      functionAppScaleLimit: 200
      minimumElasticInstanceCount: 1
    }
    scmSiteAlsoStopped: false
    clientAffinityEnabled: false
    clientCertEnabled: false
    clientCertMode: 'Required'
    hostNamesDisabled: false
    customDomainVerificationId: 'A2F1C01871825D2A3075E4B0EAEC8E4E032E553613899119EBB1333B87B53B96'
    containerSize: 1536
    dailyMemoryTimeQuota: 0
    httpsOnly: true
    redundancyMode: 'None'
    storageAccountRequired: false
    keyVaultReferenceIdentity: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}

resource sites_HSLDFSAzureCustomerPortalApiFunctions_name_ftp 'Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies@2021-02-01' = {
  parent: FunctionApp
  name: 'ftp'
  location: 'UK South'
  properties: {
    allow: true
  }
}

resource sites_HSLDFSAzureCustomerPortalApiFunctions_name_scm 'Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies@2021-02-01' = {
  parent: FunctionApp
  name: 'scm'
  location: 'UK South'
  properties: {
    allow: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bicep, ARM and Terraform aren't always used to deploy the code since depending on the language runtime you're using there may be a separate CI/CD process to build, test and publish that code on to the infrastructure you have declared within your IaC.

You can however use: `az functionapp deployment source config-zip` or `func azure functionapp publish` or if you're using Azure DevOps, GitHub Actions then you may have an entirely different pipeline for your code deployment vs your IaC.

I did see an example of Bicep deploying the code here: https://www.clounce.com/cloud/azure/azure-functions-with-file-contents-using-bicep

This makes use of the `loadTextContent('filename')` within files property of the resouce declaration:

```
files: {
  'index.js': loadTextContent('get.js')
}
```

Not tested this but I would be reluctant to trust the underlying API's to detect code changes vs Infrastructure changes.